# schedule task in windows 2008 server for php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have shared hosting on windows 2008 server and one project in php.

actually i want to run one php file once in a day automatically...

> i want to run one schedule task once
>   in day.

```
      any php code, jquery or ajax
```

for information.
i have access to ftp to up load files to my domain but i don't have sever access and its windows 2008 server.

how can i run schedule task in php on windows 2008 server?

Thanks

Comment: I'm really curious what "jQuery" or "ajax" have to do with this question ...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the server where you can set a schedule job then below are your probable options:

1. Create a php file on server W(windows2008) then if you have a free hosting account at server L(Linux) where you can setup cron job, then creating a CURL to access server W would do.
2. If your page is access often the creating a JS script with setTimeout("myAjaxFunction", 10000) would also do but it's an awkward approach as you assumed that user browser open accessing yoursite somewhere else.